# How to separate 1 record to multiple records?

Tags: sql

I want to use SQL to separate 1 record to multiple records

Original Table:

```
+---------+------+------+------+
| orderid | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 |
+---------+------+------+------+
| 1234    | 5    | 6    | 7    |
+---------+------+------+------+
```

I want to split to :

```
+---------+------+------+------+
| orderid | qty1 | qty2 | qty3 |
+---------+------+------+------+
| 1234    | 5    |      |      |
+---------+------+------+------+
| 1234    |      | 6    |      |
+---------+------+------+------+
| 1234    |      |      | 7    |
+---------+------+------+------+
```

How to do this, please help me,thanks!

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Do you expect these extra rows to be inserts or are there already additional `orderid` rows with `NULL or ''` for the `qty1`, `qty2`, `qty3`?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag with the appropriate database.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
SELECT orderid , qty1 ,NULL, NULL FROM  Order_Tbl  
UNION ALL
SELECT orderid , NULL, qty2, NULL  FROM  Order_Tbl  
UNION ALL
SELECT orderid , NULL ,NULL, qty3 FROM  Order_Tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Some dialects of SQL support explicit lateral joins.  Otherwise, if you care about performance, you can use `cross join`.  Something like this:

```
select t.orderid,
       (case when n.n = 1 then qty1 end) as qty1,
       (case when n.n = 2 then qty2 end) as qty2,
       (case when n.n = 3 then qty3 end) as qty3
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n) n;
```

More typically when splitting data like this, you would want all the values in a single column, with perhaps another column specifying the original column:

```
select t.orderid, n.n,
       (case when n.n = 1 then qty1
             when n.n = 2 then qty2
             when n.n = 3 then qty3
        end) as qty
from t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 as n) n;
```

Comment: I was working so hard to produce an answer, performing a `CROSS APPLY` on the table itself (ex. `CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('qty1',qty1),('qty2',qty2),('qty3',qty3)
                 ) CA (COL,VAL)`, but was returning 3 rows exactly the same. Couldn't figure out how to nullify/blank the results on each row like the example above, nicely done!